# Display oracle column info data type info in condensed form similar to table DDL

Tags: oracle

I would like to display column info from the ALL_TAB_COLUMNS view much in the same condensed way that you see when one views the columns's data when looking at the DDL for the table.

In other words, I would like to take the info in the columns of ALL_TAB_COLUMNS such as DATA_TYPE, DATA_PRECISION, DATA_SCALE, etc and display the column type in the "formatted" form that you would expect to see in table ddl script.

```
COL1 VARCHAR2(10)
COL2 NUMBER(*,0), 
COL3 NUMBER(15, 2)
```

I realize that I could take a stab at doing it myself with a case statement but I figured I would probably encounter some uncommon column definitionb whwere I would get it wrong and would would rather borrow this code, if I could find it.

I tried to look at the code for the function get_ddl function but I couldn't find it.

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','Table_NAME','Owner') from DUAL
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You already have this output in `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','Table_NAME','Owner')` output. Yes there is much more information but you could try to remove what you don't need with some SUBSTR or REPLACE SQL statement.

Or you can customize DBMS_METADATA in the current session with:

```
set long 5000
set pagesize 1000
BEGIN
  2  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
  3  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'PRETTY', true);
  4  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', false);
  5  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'STORAGE', false);
  6  END;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('TABLE', 'T', user) from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','T',USER)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "SYS"."T"
   (    "OWNER" VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "OBJECT_NAME" VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "SUBOBJECT_NAME" VARCHAR2(128),
    "OBJECT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "DATA_OBJECT_ID" NUMBER,
    "OBJECT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(23),
    "CREATED" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "LAST_DDL_TIME" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "TIMESTAMP" VARCHAR2(19),
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(7),
    "TEMPORARY" VARCHAR2(1),
    "GENERATED" VARCHAR2(1),
    "SECONDARY" VARCHAR2(1),
    "NAMESPACE" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "EDITION_NAME" VARCHAR2(128),
    "SHARING" VARCHAR2(13),
    "EDITIONABLE" VARCHAR2(1),
    "ORACLE_MAINTAINED" VARCHAR2(1)
   ) ;
```

Comment: I tried to look at the underlying get_ddl function in SYS.dbms_metadata but the function is encrypted. I don't appear to have access. I was looking to borrow some of the SQL in that function pertaining to my goal, but I don't have access.